# My grandfather passed away during the Second World War. - doesn't necessarily mean he was killed because of the war, right?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

A:

> My grandfather passed away during the Second World War.

B:

> Your grandfather must have been a brave soldier.

A:

> No, he fell down at home and killed himself.

This is a dialogue in a movie, I guess. I forgot where I heard it from.
It seems that the event just serves as a time reference here.
Therefore, I have come to the conclusion that without a clear context, it is up to the listener to interpret a sentence like this one.
Does my point make sense?

More examples like:

**Example 1**

> After last Friday's party, I went to her place to play card games.

-Doesn't necessarily mean I was at last Friday's party.

**Example 2**

> During my brother's wedding, I was playing games and watching TV at home.

-The wedding is just a time reference.

Comment: It is up to the speaker or writer to supply enough context.

Comment: The first quote seems as if it might be a joke. Often, saying someone died during a war would imply it was because of the war, so there is an element of surprise when the war and the death are unconnected, hence humour. Similarly "He died hunting lions in Africa!" might imply the lions ate him, but he might have died of some other unrelated reason. Or the famous joke "My father was a bus driver. I want to die peacefully in my sleep, like him. Not screaming and terrified like his passengers."

Comment: But what actually is the English language question here? Are you uncertain about what "during" means?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey are Examples 1 and 2 correct English sentences where the events just serve as time references?

Comment: @StuartF - there is an unfortunate one about the speaker's grandfather falling from a watchtower while drunk. I last heard the bus driver one told by Nicholas Parsons.

Comment: @StuartF - maybe it's just me, but I think of 'pass away' as a euphemism in connection with a peacetime (and peaceful) death. My father's brother _died_ at El Alamein (_was killed_ at that place, even). As we all know, Linda Lovelace's grandmother went down on the _Titanic_.

Comment: As usual _it depends on context_. There is nothing grammatically incorrect about them, but if you weren't at the party there seems no obvious connection between it and  'going to her house' unless the party had taken place there. In (2), it would be more natural to say _At the time of my brother's wedding_ or _While my brother was getting married in [place]_.

Comment: If some died *because* of the war, you'd perhaps say something like "He was shot down over Hamburg" or "he was killed in the war". When someone is said to 'pass away' it generally implies a peaceful departure.

Comment: What @WeatherVane said. No-one talks about soldiers "passing away" if they're killed in battle, and it's an unusual term to use even of non-combatants killed *because* of a war (killed by enemy bombs on civilian targets, for example). The default assumption for OP's text is that the grandfather died (most likely peacefully, of old age) within the date range of WW2.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything special about English in this regard.  You could say "祖父は第二次世界大戦中に亡くなりました / やっぱり勇敢だったに違いない" For example and it would have exactly the same effect.

Comment: In the party example, it could actually imply that you weren't at the party, for example if it's clear from context that the party occurred at "her place," in which case you were waiting for it to end before going for the card game.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that "passed away" is not typically used for soldiers, but I'd be surprised if it weren't possible to find examples of it [pause] and sure enough, phrase searches for "passed away in X" where X is a _recent_ war or a place where a war has happened _recently_ do yield some meaningful results. The fact that X has to be recent probably reflects a growing taboo in the US (and perhaps elsewhere) around the use of words like "died" and "killed" and a corresponding increase in the prevalence of euphemisms.

Comment: @phoog: I wouldn't take any notice of a few "unusual" usages on the Internet today, given that there are lots of native Anglophones whose familiarity with idiomatic English is less than great, *and* a lot of English text on the net today is written by non-native speakers anyway. Unless I find plenty of support in published written context (Google Books), I don't attach too much credibility to usages that don't seem "natural" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers native anglophones are by definition speaking idiomatic English.  Some of the search results could have been created by non-native speakers, but most of the ones I looked at were from people in the US whose relatives had been killed in combat in US military service.  Published written content doesn't always reflect the way the language is spoken by actual people.  Here, however, is a more formal example, from the Congressional Medal of Honor Society: https://www.cmohs.org/news-events/commemoration/remembering-medal-of-honor-recipients-who-have-sacrificed-their-lives-in-service/

Comment: To quote: "Keith Ware received the Medal of Honor during World War II for his fearless leadership in taking a critical hill and inspiring the soldiers under his command. While continuing his service in the Vietnam War, he passed away in the line of duty."  His [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_L._Ware#Death) explains that he was killed in a helicopter crash attributed to anti-aircraft fire, the second US general officer to die  in Vietnam (the first having died of a heart attack).

Comment: @phoog: Well, I don't want to argue about it. But I'm solidly behind Weathervane's observation that *to 'pass away' generally implies a peaceful departure*, and that's how I'd use it myself. And I don't think it's a very good idea for non-native *learners* to be given the impression a soldier could "pass away" on the battlefield, not least because they might be more inclined to use "relatively unusual" constructions like that simply because it seems more in line with how *their* language & culture addresses such issues. And that's not how you'd want to learn a foreign language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I remember a late-1960s Marty Feldman TV sketch where he plays a young man who encounters a grumpy old git in a train carriage. The old git says 'I died in the war for people like you!'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Haha, good one! Memory can play funny tricks, but I'd bet any money Colonel Blimp there would never have said *I **passed away** in the war for people like you!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I personally, and I daresay I'm nearer that point than many on here, can't bear the idea of 'passing away'. It sounds such a polite, lily-livered thing to do. I'm going to bloody well _die_, and so is everyone else. _I saw a tweet featuring a portrait of the actress Sharon Tate, with a caption informing us that she 'passed on this day in 1969'. That’s one way of putting it.’_ - Guy Kelly (quoted in a Daily Telegraph opinion piece)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - when I was aged four one of my grandmothers died, and I asked my mother what had happened to her. 'Nanny was very tired, so she went to sleep' was the answer. Guess who wouldn't go to bed for the next week. You used to see 'Fell asleep in Jesus' on gravestones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I 'observed' that _passing away_ is used about peacetime and peaceful death a whole hour before Weathervane! Did I taint my comment with the crack about Linda Lovelace?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I must admit it took me a minute to see what you meant there. I don't recall precise timing (I drift in and out of this site while doing other things), but most likely I saw yours and weathervane's "peacefully" comments (and maybe a few before it) at the same time. It wasn't that the Lovelace crack soured me (though I recall thinking it might be a bit near the knuckle) but it did draw my attention away from the point made earlier in the comment. When I was endorsing the point made by you both, Weathervane's version was right above me, so I it got both the mench and the uptick!

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, your original sentence would be normally understood to mean your grandfather was a soldier, which is exactly how "B" understands it.

Similarly, in Example 1, any normal person would infer that you were at the party.

With Example 2, it's impossible that you were at your brother's wedding, so there's no chance someone will infer you were there.

Comment: If somebody "died in the war" I'd assume the death was directly related to the war. If they "died during the war" I'm not so sure. WWII in particular affected everybody in the countries involved even if they weren't directly involved, so it's the kind of time marker you might use just to refer to a certain period of time, even for people who weren't in the armed forces or otherwise fighting the war.

Comment: It wouldn't take more than a few words to establish sufficient context for example 1 to imply that the speaker was waiting for the party at "her place" to end before going there for a purpose other than attending the party.

Comment: @ThePhoton any sort of context could also establish that the grandfather couldn't have been a soldier.  For example, "my grandfather was blind from birth; he died during the second world war."

Comment: @phoog. Sure. And things like "I was born during the war" or "I volunteered for the fire brigade during the war" are very common also.

Comment: @ThePhoton - my cousin was born during a German air raid in the Blitz, but there's no suggestion that she was dropped by the Luftwaffe.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, exactly my point. I was born during the Vietnam War but that doesn't suggest that enemy action caused my birth. (My birth may have helped my father get a draft deferment, but I have no idea if my parents were motivated by that idea)

Comment: @ThePhoton It's all about context. Wars cause so much death that if you say someone died *during* a war, the natural assumption is that they died *in* the war. Wars do not cause births, so if you say someone was born *during* a war, nobody will assume they were born on the front lines. That's what my answer means.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe we can embellish this sentence with indicating time:

"My grandfather passed away during the time of second world war."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "during the time of second world war" is most definitely *not* idiomatically valid English, for *several* reasons.